# java.text.parseException:unparsable date

Tags: java, parseexception

i am getting this error while i am trying to convert a string into date.
unparasable data
Below is my code:-

```
String str = "hello"
```

Comment: `format` doesn't return a Date. Please post code that at least compiles (or ask a question about a compiler error).

Answer (score 3):

Second is missing at your parse String `str`. So, to parse it you should not include second format at `SimpleDateFormat` `pattern`. Also correct the day and Month format. Look at the declaration of `df`

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a");//Remove :ss
```

To know details of pattern, go through this [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

#### Edit

```
String date2 = sdformatter.format(date1);// format method return String.
                                         //Should declare with String
```

#### Full Code

```
    String str = "25-Nov-2013 06:00 AM";
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a");//Remove :ss
    SimpleDateFormat sdformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    Date date1=null;
    try {
        date1 = df.parse(str);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    String date2 = sdformatter.format(date1);
    System.out.println(date2);
```

Comment: i did as you told but i guess its giving error in following line:-Date date1 = df.parse(str);                                                              // i guess its not able to convert str(which is a string type) into date1(Date type).

Comment: On applying catch,                                                catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("Caught " + e);
}                                                                    its showing following error still- parseException:unparseable date:

Comment: Thanks Masud. Its working now .Problem was"MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss a" written instead of "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a"

Answer (score 0):

According to str format you should write your SimpleDateFormat,

```
(25-Nov-2013 06:00 AM ---> dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a) and for 
(25-Nov-2013 06:00:30 AM-----> dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a)
```

will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
long newerdate = new Date().parse("25-Nov-2013 06:30 AM");
java.text.SimpleDateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a");
String data = df.format(newerdate);
System.out.println(data);
```